# using WHERE condition1 AND condition2 in ::selectraw

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

I am using ::selectRaw inside my PHP function and I need that statement to get two conditions. In my case, I am using my `category_id` column

I tried to do two where but seems like these conflict with each other:

```
    $query = self::selectRaw((is_array($fields)?implode(", ",$fields):$fields))
                   ->where('category_id', '=', 1)
                   ->where('category_id', '=', 2)
                   ->where(function($q) use($search){
        if($search){
            return $q->where(['group_name' => $search]);
        }
    });
```

how do I translate `WHERE category_id = 1 AND category_id = 2` in the `::selectRaw` query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the whereIn function.

```
$query = self::selectRaw((is_array($fields)?implode(", ",$fields):$fields))
                   ->whereIn('category_id', [1,2])
                   ->where(function($q) use($search){
        if($search){
            return $q->where(['group_name' => $search]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: quick and easy answer, thanks!